# How to display a specific text on successfull uninstallation

Tags: wix, installation

I'm creating a setup.exe bundle for my msi with WIX.
I have a Msi which installs my application. This app depends on a number of other packages.
So I created a bundle which installs the Msi and these packages.
To specify how should setup's wizard pages be displayed I use some Theme.xml.

But I can not find out how to show different Text on Success Page in case of installation and uninstallation (e.g. "The app was successfully installed"/ "The app was successfully removed")

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the message in theme.wxl file which is pointed by LocalizationFile attribute.

```
<Bundle ...
 .............
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
        LicenseUrl=""
        LogoFile="Logo.png"
        SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
        LocalizationFile="Theme.wxl"
        ThemeFile="Theme.xml"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

........
</Bundle>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how depending on what is going on (installation/uninstallation) can I switch which message should be displayed? Couldn't You give me an example or something like.

Comment: This link may help you.( https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockplusie/blob/master/installer/bootstrap-theme.wxl )

Comment: I mean the text on last page (<Page Name="Success">). What message will be displayed in case of successful uninstall? "Setup Successful" isn't it?

Comment: @bilboquet have you got your answer? were you success to change the name?